# Getting stackoverflow error in widget in flutter that show a simple text

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I make a widget that takes a string as a parameter and show it with a special case

this is the widget :

```
class Hometext extends StatelessWidget {
  final Size size;
  final String text;
  final bool islogin;
  Hometext({@required this.size, @required this.text, @required this.islogin});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: islogin ? size.height * 0.06 : size.height * 0.03,
        left: size.width * 0.05,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Data().colorslist['black'],
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: islogin ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: size.width * 0.08,
            height: size.height * 0.02,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Data().colorslist['darkgreen'],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when using this widget the debug console gives me a StackOverflow error it gave me this error for a lot of  widget in my application and I don,t know why it crashed my app for weeks and I don,t know what to do to deal with it

this is an error :

```
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was
Hometext
lib\screens\wholescreen.dart:31
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin._init (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:217:18)
#2      _LinkedHashMapMixin._rehash (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:199:7)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin._insert (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:247:7)
#4      _LinkedHashMapMixin.[]= (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:296:7)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Data class :

```
class Data {
  Map colorslist = {
    'black': Color.fromRGBO(10, 9, 8, 1),
    'darkgreen': Color.fromRGBO(34, 51, 59, 1),
    'offwhite': Color.fromRGBO(234, 224, 213, 1),
  };

  List pageviewdata = [
    'lib/assets/pageview1.jpg',
    'lib/assets/pageview2.jpg',
    'lib/assets/pageview3.jpg',
  ];

  List pageviewnumbers = [0, 1, 2];

  List categories = [
    Categories(name: 'Health&Beuty', image: 'lib/assets/health&beuty.jpg'),
    Categories(name: 'Books', image: 'lib/assets/books.jpg'),
    Categories(name: 'Fashion', image: 'lib/assets/fashion.jpg'),
    Categories(name: 'Electronics', image: 'lib/assets/electronics.jpg'),
  ];

  List<Drawerlisttile> drawerlisttile = [
    Drawerlisttile(name: 'Home', icon: Icon(Icons.home,color: Data().colorslist['offwhite'])),
    Drawerlisttile(name: 'Cartlist', icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,color: Data().colorslist['offwhite'])),
    Drawerlisttile(name: 'Orders', icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_rounded,color: Data().colorslist['offwhite'])),
    Drawerlisttile(name: 'Settings', icon: Icon(Icons.settings,color: Data().colorslist['offwhite'])),
  ];
}
```

Comment: could you add `Data` code?

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `colorslist` static inside `Data` class

when you create an instance of it using `Data()`, then a `drawerlisttile` is being instantiated which creates `Data()`

in other words, creating `Data` creates multiple instances of `Data`, hence the overflow

```dart
class Data {
  static Map colorslist = {
    'black': Color.fromRGBO(10, 9, 8, 1),
    'darkgreen': Color.fromRGBO(34, 51, 59, 1),
    'offwhite': Color.fromRGBO(234, 224, 213, 1),
  };

  List<Drawerlisttile> drawerlisttile = [
    Drawerlisttile(name: 'Home', icon: Icon(Icons.home,color: Data.colorslist['offwhite'])),
    Drawerlisttile(name: 'Cartlist', icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,color: Data.colorslist['offwhite'])),
    Drawerlisttile(name: 'Orders', icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_rounded,color: Data.colorslist['offwhite'])),
    Drawerlisttile(name: 'Settings', icon: Icon(Icons.settings,color: Data.colorslist['offwhite'])),
  ];
}
```